# Missing baggage Swissport at Dublin

Tags: luggage, delays, dublin, mumbai, cairo

It's day 3 after landing in Dublin from Mumbai to Cairo and Cairo to Dublin. Swissport handles the baggage at Dublin airport. Baggage was delayed and we were told that the baggage would arrive within 2 days. We filled a form for delayed luggage at airport. On the tracing website, it still shows that tracing of bag continues. I am a bit tensed. What should be my potential actions? Please advise.
I can't reach Swissport or Egyptair on phone. Have dropped them a email but no reply since 2 days.

Comment: File a delayed baggage claim with your travel insurance company

Comment: It has taken that long for me to be reunited with baggage after a direct flight, London to Budapest, so do not give up hope yet.